# Copying Data to other sheet by and filling chromatically

Tags: xml, excel, vba, data-binding, excel-formula

Hi all (really new to vba programming - started today) suppose i would want to copy data from one sheet to another based on a logic statement and fill the second sheet from top to bottom (ie no empty rows between each other) How would i start to go about something like this.

[image]

From the above on sheet one, i would like the following on sheet 2 - since row 1,3,4 and 7 contained answers

[image]

But this is test data - the real file contains about a 1000 entries

Thanks for the assist guys.!

A

Comment: if you absolutely need VBA see `AutoFilter` method and `SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)` property

Comment: @ScottHoltzman - is there another way? Please enlighten me.... I would really be greatful.....

Comment: looks like you figured out the answer on your own ... or are on the way to getting it, at least :)

Comment: no - it actually worked3

Answer (score 0):

This is the framework for the answer

```
Sub test()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Sheets("Patient Database").Activate
    Selection.AutoFilter

    With ActiveSheet.Range("$A$2:$D$10")
        .AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:=">0"
        .Offset(1, 0).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, .Columns.Count).Copy
    End With

    Sheets("Sheet2").Activate



    Sheets("Sheet1").Activate
    ActiveSheet.Range("A2").AutoFilter
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```